# How to enforce the use of -it when running a container in Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to force the -it when I run a container, even if the user doesn't send it, enforcing it somehow.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: No. Whoever runs the container decides what the container has access to. The best you can do is have the container fail with a useful error message if no TTY is attached.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do?

No.

> How to enforce the use of -it when running a container in Docker?

You would have to write a docker plugin that returns some exit code in case a container without interactive and tty is started.